# How long does the DocuSign refresh token lives?

Tags: api, authentication, token, docusignapi

we work on custom software integrated with DocuSign. There is a question:

How long does the DocuSign refresh token live? 
Is it possible it lives one year?

We have found similar question here:  https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00083606 but without an answer

Who has some experience with DocuSign API - maybe you could help us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long the refresh token expires for the DocuSign API oAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014953/how-long-the-refresh-token-expires-for-the-docusign-api-oauth)