# Is the refresh token minimum expiration one year?

Tags: token, docusignapi

In continuation to the following question: [How long the refresh token expires for the DocuSign API oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014953/how-long-the-refresh-token-expires-for-the-docusign-api-oauth)

Let me present the question differently - under which circumstances can a refresh token live for at least 1 year? I.e. we need the refresh token to be expired in not less than 1 year.

Is this possible?
What special circumstances may arise? (purchase of a special account) Or what is the MAXIMUM length of life of refresh token in your system? We use Authorization Code Grant.

Answer (score 1):

You can request the "extended" scope in addition to the "signature" scope.  When extended scope is requested, the refresh_token will be given the maximum allowable lifetime based on the security policies defined by the authenticating users or their organization.

However I doubt that you'll get a year's worth of refreshes.

Why do you want such a long period? The Authorization Code Grant flow is for when a human is present. And since the human is present, he or she can re-authenticate when the refresh token expires.

If your application is a "Service Integration" that runs on its own then you should use the [Legacy Header Authentication technique](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html). It does not expire.