# Dosusign API access token extended expiry

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign to send the documents to the the signers. with the access token generated with this link on my account :

`https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator`

This token have expiry of 8 hours and i was in the development mode so it did not bother me to refresh the token after every 8 hours. But now as we are going to be live i want to have my application renew this token automatically.

According to the api there is refresh token but still it it have a limit of 30 days. while i want to be free from this refreshing the token. is there any way.

it is written in the documentation but i am unable to fully understand the documentation.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014953/how-long-the-refresh-token-expires-for-the-docusign-api-oauth has more info about keeping tokens alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access Tokens received via the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow usually have an 8 hour life. The accompanying Refresh Token usually has a 30 day life.

If extended scope is not requested in the authentication flow, then the Refresh Token, when used will return a new Refresh Token that will have the same expiration date as the original.

But if extended scope is requested, then, when the Refresh Token is used, the returned (new) Refresh Token will normally be good for an additional 30 days from that time.

So if extended scope is requested, and the user logs in at least once every 30 days, then the original and newly provided Refresh Tokens will enable the user to never have to re-authenticate himself or herself.

Comment: what if i want to free my application from these `30 days life` ? i should have run cron jobs to update the refresh token after every 8 hours?

Comment: the refresh token is for 30 days, if you request extended scope and the user logs in every day - then you won't need them to log in again at all.

Comment: what if user does not log in in 30 days and he check docusign application after 1 or 2 months? also to fetch the first authorization code do i have to manually hit the url or there is api call ? as stated here [link](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)

Comment: first question - they'll have to login again
second question - you do have to hit the url the first time

Comment: so is it a good approach to store the access token and refresh token in the database and run a cron job after every 5 or 10 days to get new refresh token ?

Comment: is there any way to get it programmatically  like curl get request?

Comment: first question - it's an ok idea if you secure everything correct
second question - no, you cannot, for security purposes, there has to be a human interaction to accept consent of the app.

Comment: @thank you for your comment and bearing with me. just a last question as i have get the authorization code i should get the access token and refresh token once? then i should proceed further with the refresh token so on. Is it a correct workflow i am guessing ?

Comment: here is a useful article - https://medium.com/@sanjuctab/using-a-refresh-token-to-obtain-an-access-token-from-docusign-3c297eb51886 please see if after reading the article it's still not clear. Also, if you are good - please mark this question as answered. thanks!

Comment: thank you for link unfortunately i am working in `php` not in `nodejs`

Comment: sorry, I understand, but the ideas are the same. It won't show you PHP code but at least answer your question about the workflow