# Which is the error returned when a DocuSign refresh token is expired?

Tags: docusignapi

My team is working in an integration between an **ASP NET MVC App** and **DocuSign** using [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) with the following scopes: `signature` and `extended`.

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant#using-refresh-tokens) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014953/how-long-the-refresh-token-expires-for-the-docusign-api-oauth), I know the `refresh_token` **typically expires in around 30 days**, but it **may change at any time**.

So, as I can't know for sure when a `refresh_token` will expire (so I can have a recurrent Job to update it, for instance), and since for me to have an invalid `refresh_token` I'd have to wait about 30 days to see which error it returns, so I can handle it, my question is...

Does anyone know which is the error returned when trying to refresh an `access_token` and the `refresh_token` is expired? Would that be *Invalid Grant*? What exact *error code* or *identifier* it returns so I can handle it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't been able to use an *expired refresh token* yet, but based on [OAuth 2.0 RFC (Issuing an Access Token > Error Response)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) I strongly believe it'll return `invalid_grant` for expired refresh tokens, once it says...

> `invalid_grant`: The provided authorization grant or **refresh token** is invalid, expired, revoked...

And I found this [DocuSign REST API Guide, version 2](https://www.slideshare.net/mikebz/docusign-rest-api-guide-v2-29528966) PDF (although it isn't v2.1) with information about the errors returned by DocuSign OAuth2 endpoints:

> [image: DocuSign REST API Guide]

So, based on those info and the discussions with *@InbarGazit* and *@LarryK*, **my conclusion is...**

I'll **redirect** the user to the Authentication page when an error occurs while **trying to refresh** the `access_token` (using the `refresh_token`), and the error returned is the kind of error that could be resolved by re-authenticating, which seems to be those: `invalid_client`, `invalid_grant` and `unauthorized_client`. Code sample:

```
var redirectUserErrors = new[] { "invalid_client", "invalid_grant", "unauthorized_client" };
// [...]
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(oAuthUri, data);
var stringContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var errorObject = JObject.Parse(stringContent);
    string errorCode = errorObject["error"] != null ? errorObject["error"].ToString() : null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorCode) && 
        redirectUserErrors.Any(err => err.Equals(errorCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
       throw new DocuSignAuthRedirectException($"An error has occurred when trying to refresh the access token. Error code: '{errorCode}'");
       // [The custom exception needs to be handled outside, so the User can be redirected to the Auth page]
    }
}
```

Besides, although I'll try to refresh the `acess_token` when it's about to expire, I'll also check for the `USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error code when using it to consume the API, and if it occurs I'll call the *refresh token logic* which already handle the types or errors that require the user to be redirected (this because the `access_token` might be invalid but not expired, which I suppose happens when the access is revoked from the app, for instance).

Comment: This documentation has been pulled from the Developer Center because it references an older implementation of OAuth that is deprecated and no longer supported. The error codes you are seeing here are not an exact match for what you'll see if you're using the DocuSign Account Server (`account.docusign.com`) for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you don't make assumptions about error messages and conditions under which you get them. To solve this problem, I would implement code that attempt to use the refresh token when you original access token does not work (error) and attempts to ask the user to start again the login process when the refresh token does not work (error).
The reason (expired, password modified, access revoked or even some other bug) does not matter. For example, if the reason is that consent to the app was revoked - the process of authorization code grant would ask the user for consent again. So this way - you handle it all without having to have special code for each case.
Lastly, it's possible error messages will change and even the logic for when you get them may change for all sorts of reasons. Robust applications handle all errors correctly.

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit, but it doesn't seem for me that handle any possible error by asking the user for consent again is a good approach either. Imagine, for instance, one has messed up with the App configurations used in the integration (although it's unlikely and ideally it shouldn't happen, it might), the user would be asked to consent permissions but it wouldn't solve the problem. I agree to cover more scenarios than just *"refresh token expired"*, but there should be a way for me to identify if the errors I receive would really be solved by consenting to the app again.

Comment: consent is only required once, I just gave that as an example. What I mean is to re-authenticate the user. That is just good practice to do that once in a while.

Comment: I mentioned *consent* but I know it's only required once, unless I change the scopes being used or the user revokes access to the app. But my point is... I don't think asking the user to re-authenticate when **any error** occurs is a good approach, because there might be some errors where just re-authenticating wouldn't solve that. I may go that way if I can't know the possible errors to handle them, although I wouldn't like to.

Comment: yes, you are right, some errors (say your client secret is wrong) won't be helped, but these are all errors on your end, not the user, not normal/expected errors that can happen in the course of using an API.

Comment: That's why I'd prefer redirecting the user to the login page only when a set of errors occur, and not with any error. I've found this [DocuSign REST API Guide, version 2](https://www.slideshare.net/mikebz/docusign-rest-api-guide-v2-29528966) PDF (althoug it isn't v2.1), where the topic **OAuth2 Response Codes** lists the possible error codes, so I guess I can base on them to redirect the user (probably redirecting the user when the error is one of those: [`invalid_client`, `invalid_grant`, `unauthorized_client`, `unsupported_grant_type`], but not this one: `invalid_request`).

Comment: sounds like a plan

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `extended` scope, you'll get a new refresh token (good for another 30 days) each time you use the refresh token to get a new set of {access and refresh tokens}.

So if you make sure to use the refresh token whenever it reaches 25 days old, then you'll always be good (unless the user has withdrawn consent in the meanwhile).

Of course, if your application uses the DocuSign API each day, then the refresh token will never be more than a day old.

I believe you will get an *invalid grant* error if the refresh token has expired before you try to use it.

Anytime your app has a problem using the refresh token, ask your user to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks @Larry... I also suppose errors using the refresh token would return *invalid grant*, but so far I guess I'll need to wait 30 days to be sure. 
My app depends on the user to decide to use DocuSign, which means through our App the user is able to send documents to be signed (envelope). So I can't ensure the user will use it frequently to constantly update the token.

I could have a recurring job to update it before 30 days, but since the documentation says *"it expires in **around 30 days**, but it **may change at any time**"*, I'm not comfortable with that approach.

Comment: Those statements in the docs are CYA. As of this writing, the refresh token lasts 30 days. (But if the user has withdrawn consent then the refresh won't work, and the user can do that at any time.)

Comment: I Guess I'll handle the errors based on the error codes I've found in the [DocuSign REST API Guide, version 2](https://www.slideshare.net/mikebz/docusign-rest-api-guide-v2-29528966) PDF. Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722812/which-is-the-error-returned-when-a-docusign-refresh-token-is-expired#comment111026726_62722930) for more info.