# How to request for an extended scope refresh token in docusign while refreshing access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

I have included the 'extended' scope while generating the authorization URI for oauth code grant flow, but while refreshing the access token, in the response I am getting the scope as 'signature'. How to get the refresh token with extended scope when refreshing the access token. I have attached my code to get the access token from refresh token.

```
        auth_string = "{0}:{1}".format(
            DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_ID, DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_SECRET
        )
        auth_encoded_hash = b64encode(auth_string.encode("utf-8"))
        auth_header = auth_encoded_hash.decode("utf-8")

 
        url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"

        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Basic {0}".format(auth_header),
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }

        body = {"grant_type": "refresh_token", "refresh_token": refresh_token}
        _response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
        response = _response.json() # here I am getting scope as 'signature'
```

My second follow up question on this, if the refresh token itself get expires while refreshing the access token what would be the error message I will be getting in the response above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refresh operation **request** does not include scopes.
The refresh operation **response** may include the scopes that were previously requested.

Here is the refresh operation:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic 'NWYxZTg4…………...TJkOGI2Yg==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=eyJ0eX…………...Dp_hA' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token'
```

If the refresh operation succeeds, then the response contains a new access token and a new refresh token.

**Next, throw away the old refresh token** and use the newly received refresh token until the next time.

In other words:

- the first refresh API call uses the refresh token returned by the Authorization Code grant flow
- then each subsequent refresh API call uses the refresh token returned by the prior refresh API call

[Blog post about using refresh tokens](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/authorization-code-grant-refresh-tokens)

Comment: Thank you! Yes the refresh operation doesn't include scope, but the refresh operation response contains scope='signature', So I got confused with that. To understand the scenario with the signature scope, do I get a new refresh token here during the refresh operation, even If we get should I need to use the newer token or the older one because anyway the lifetime will be same here.

Comment: For each refresh operation, use the refresh token returned by the prior refresh operation.

Answer (score 1):

The "extended" scope is needed when you originally consent and get the token from the user so that the refresh token will not expire for 30 days. It is not needed every time you use said refresh token to obtain a new access token.

Error messages for an expired token will typically get an *invalid grant* error, but the error is subject to change, you should handle all errors and not look for a particular error string.

See [Which is the error returned when a DocuSign refresh token is expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722812/which-is-the-error-returned-when-a-docusign-refresh-token-is-expired) for similar question/answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just to verify my thoughts,  once after refreshing the token, I should use the newly generated refresh token (one which I get in the response above) right for generating the access token the next time? I suppose that will be the one which have the validity extended to next 30 days.

Comment: You can use the same refresh_token you originally generated with "extended" scope. If you keep using the new refresh tokens - you don't need extended scope

Comment: @InbarGazit -- you must use the newly received refresh token from the refresh operation.