# How to added extended scope in Docusign token creation

Tags: docusignapi

I need to add extended scope so that my token will last for 30 days before expiration. Where do I set it? Is it at token generation as per below

`curl --header "Authorization: Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS" --data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE&**scope=extended**" --request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`

or at refresh token:

`POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token Authorization: Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN&**scope=extended**`

See documentations: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the *extended* scope is used in addition to the *signature* scope, not as a replacement.

Second, this scope is requested at the time of consent.

Third, this scope does not affect the *access token* life.  Instead, it means that when you use the refresh token you are refreshing the refresh token as well, such that you get a further 30 days before the refresh token expires.

The extended scope is ideal for integrations in a business app that is used quite often by the user.  As long as they are using the integration on a recurring basis, such as an app that is used daily or weekly, then as long as they don't go on an extended holiday, they will not need to re-authenticate.  However, they will need to if they missed a 30-day expiration period.  This gives regular use users convenience while still maintaining a reasonable level of security.

Answer (score 0):

The **extended scope** is needed when you originally consent and get the token from the user so that the refresh token will not expire for 30 days. It is not needed every time you use said refresh token to obtain a new access token.

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775704/how-to-request-for-an-extended-scope-refresh-token-in-docusign-while-refreshing) on Stack Overflow.