# DocuSign API - Authorization Code Grant Flow Refresh Question

Tags: docusignapi

I'm about to start work on implementing the Authorization Code Grant flow for authentication with the DocuSign API. I'm just trying to clarify if the following is correct:

1. I first authenticate and get an access token which is good for 3600 seconds (10 minutes)
2. I also get a refresh token which expires typically in 30 days
3. I can refresh the access token after it has expired as long as I do so before the refresh token expires in 30 days

Once I refresh the access token I have another 30 days to refresh this (unless it is refreshed earlier).

Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DocuSign API per se, but, yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work with refresh tokens and access tokens in OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first assumption is wrong. First, 3600 seconds is 1 hour not 10 minutes. Second Authentication code grant access_token is valid for 8 hours or 28800 seconds. you can read more [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-best-practice/). Regarding your refresh token, it depends on either you used extended scope.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014953/how-long-the-refresh-token-expires-for-the-docusign-api-oauth) explains it in details. You can read even more in this [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/) in Step2 - refresh_token section